HTML images not showing up
I'm trying to make the images from here show up here but nothing i try is working.
I've tried changing the paths. I've even tried separating the HTML paths and putting them in the CSS property (as shown here). Some help would be appreciated.

The way you have it in the Website/index.html is correct: <img src="images/logo.png". You just don't have that logo.png file in the /images/ folder.

Your path should start at "images", not "Website":
.apple-icon {
  background-image: url("images/appleMewsic.png");
  background-size: contain;
  width: 32px;
  height: 32px;
  margin: 7px;
}

I believe this is the relevant HTML:
<a rel="noopener"
   href="https://music.apple.com/yourprofile"
   target="_blank">
  <img class="apple-icon" alt="Apple Music" />
</a>


Website is part of the file path. The images folder is in a folder called website. Thus the path starts at website.

Yes but your index file is inside the Website path, so your image src will be relative to that. I reproduced your example and resolved it by using the src from my answer. Edit: here is an image of it "working" with a red border: https://i.imgur.com/M4P0Z3S.png

Would you mind sharing the HTML part of your code please?

Sure, I added the relevant HTML to the answer.

Took a little bit but I finally got it working. Thanks for your help. The problem was that I didnt define display in the css property.

Yes I see that you needed inline-block. If my answer was helpful, please consider upvoting and accepting it as the answer.
